Solving Probability from Sequential Sampling
Please consider this problem:
"There are three types of a particular disease. Type A contains 1/9 of the patients and type B contains 1/6 of patients. Therefore, type C contains 13/18 of patients. A public health research is to study this disease and conduct a sequential sampling of these patients. What is the probability that this researcher will obtain a type A patient before a type B patient?"
Now, I'm trying to understand the question and the intuition behind the solution. First, do I assume that sampling was done with replacement. Second, what is the cut-off point for the sampling? Is it just 2 sample of one patient each time or a continuous sampling until the desired event is achieved. Third, what kind of distribution would this be?
Thanks.

Why would you do two samples of one patient? You test patient number one, then patient number two, and so on, until you get an A or a B.

Ok thanks so much. So that's a geometric distribution with a "recalibrated" probability value for both A and B since C is excluded?

Hint

Why on earth would you do sampling with replacement ?

Type C patients are irrelevant for your experiment

Type A and Type B are strung out in a line in the ratio $\frac19 :\frac16 = ?$

What is the $Pr$ that the first patient you see is Type A ?



Thanks so much. I now understand the question

Glad to be of help ! $;;$ :)
